# How to write a regular expression to validate a 4 character string as a non-zero binary number?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have a string E.g `1001`, which needs to be exactly 4 chars and can be any combination of `0` and `1`, but not all zeros (all ones is ok).

I thought of:

```
^[01]{4}$
```

won't work because it accepts `0000`

I will be using PHP or JavaScript to do this.

Just adding a detail.

I will be using this to validate the answers for a multi choise questionnaire before they go in the database therefore the string will have length N depending on the number of choices for the question.

so a function to provide the general solution would be great.

Comment: Why not just test that regex along with && val > 0?

Comment: Go the whole way - parse the binary number into an integer, and then check it's greater than 0.

Comment: Agreed, I have some strings that are 40 chars long with 0s and 1s so I guess regxexp wont cut it alone.

Comment: So is your actual issue about only 4 character long binary strings, or about binary strings which are N characters in length?

Comment: N characters in length, I am using this to validate the answers for a multi choise questionnaire before they go in the database.

Comment: @roippi, _only_ parsing the binary string using either the PHP `intval($str,2)` or JavaScript `parseInt(str,2)` functions is not sufficient as neither function validates the string to only contain valid characters. The string will still need to be validated as containing only `^[01]+$`.  Given this requirement, parsing is probably not the most efficient method of accomplishing this task.

Comment: @ericsicons, Then you might want to either edit this question to reflect your actual issue, or ask another question, so you get answers to your actual issue. Either way, please leave me a comment and I will either copy my answer to the new question (with edit), or remove the portion which addresses the 4 character problem leaving the portion which addresses the the N character non-zero binary string test.

Comment: @ericsicons, If the string to be validated is answers to a multiple choice question(s?), how is it that you have string that is a fixed length non-zero binary sequence? Is it something where each Q bits (e.g. 2 bits, representing answers A, B, C, or D) is a single answer and for some reason the answers have been converted into binary strings and concatenated together?

Comment: @ericsicons, Given the number of answers that are addressing only the question you initially posted regarding a 4 character non-zero binary string, you are better off posting a new question which asks about your actual issue regarding validating a N character string to be a non-zero binary number (make sure to state PHP and/or JavaScript initially in the question and include those tags). That way you get answers which are focused on your actual issue and solutions in the languages you are going to use. If/when you do, please leave me a comment with `@Makyen` at the beginning so I am notified.

Answer (score 5):

It should work

```
^(?!0000)[01]{4}$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gS2kL3/2)

*Note:* Use `gm` as modifier

Read more about [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that actually matches characters, but then gives up the match, returning only the result: match or no match.

Pattern explanation:

```
  ^                        the beginning of the string
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
    0000                     '0000'
  )                        end of look-ahead
  [01]{4}                  any character of: '0', '1' (4 times)
  $                        end of the string
```

Comment: @Bohemian Is the regex `^(?!0000){1}[01]{4}$` functionally identical, or is there a difference that I am missing?

Comment: @shree.pat18 test it at https://regex101.com/. It doesn't work in PHP or javascript

Comment: @shree.pat18 As per your pattern it should be `^(?:(?!0000)){1}[01]{4}$`

Comment: @Bohemian, It is not reasonable to say "at last" in this instance. It was not until an hour after the question was posted when an edit was made to state that the language will be PHP or JavaScript. Without that information, assuming the regular expression can use negative look-ahead would have had the answer impose a limit on what languages the question could be about.

Comment: @Braj The link I posted did in fact show my answer was working with JS. Nevertheless, seeing that there is a better received answer here I have deleted mine.

Answer (score 0):

The regex:

```
^(1[01]{3}|01[01]{2}|001[01]|0001)$
```

Will work and does not rely on look-ahead or look-behind operations which are not, necessarily, available in all regex implementations. Although, now that the question has been edited to provide the languages which will be used: Both [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) and [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) regular expressions have negated look-ahead. In those languages, the regex `^(?!0000)[01]{4}$` will work.

The regex at the top of this answer uses multiple terms to build up successively more explicit matches as each character position is specified. The point is that there must be at least one `1` character in the matching four character string. Once a `1` character is encountered in the string, we do not care what the remaining characters are, other than being `[01]`.

The first term `1[01]{3}` will match any four `0` and `1` digits that start with `1`.  This covers all desired matching strings where the first digit is a `1` leaving only desired strings starting with `0` not yet defined as matching.

The second term `01[01]{2}` will match any four `0` and `1` digits that start with `01`.  This leaves only desired strings which start with `00` not yet defined as matching.

The third term `001[01]{2}` will match `0010` and `0011`

The fourth term `0001` matches the one desired string not matched by the other terms.

### Validate an N character long non-zero binary string:

**Use a regex comparison and a length check:**
Your comments indicate that you have much longer (e.g. 40 characters) similar strings which you need to match in other circumstances.

Given that you have the need to check various different length strings, you are probably best off creating a single function which is able to test multiple different lengths.

In JavaScript, a possibility would be:

```
function isNonZeroBinaryStringOfLengthN(str, len) {
    //True if string is all 0 or 1 with at least one 1 and is the right length.
    return (str.length == len && /^[01]*1[01]*$/.test(str) );
}
```

**It is not a good idea to *only* use the built in functions to parse the string to an integer:**
For this circumstance, you are probably best off sticking with a regex based solution rather than using either the PHP [`intval($str,2)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) or JavaScript [`parseInt(str,2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).  The reason for this is that neither function properly validates the string.

In PHP the command:

```
echo intval('011134011',2);
```

prints

```
7
```

In JavaScript the command:

```
console.log(parseInt("0101382730101",2));
```

prints:

```
5
```

This means that if you use one of the internal string->int parsing functions, you still have to separately validate the string you are passing to either function to match `^[01]{n}$`. Given that you must to that anyway, you are probably better off using the single regex and length test mentioned above without parsing the string to an int.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution is this:

```
^[01]{4}(?<=100|10|1)$
```

Based on your two possible values [0,1] you only have 8 distinct possibilities:

0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1111

Your original Regex would hit on all these values. However, the positive look-behind code ensures that the code will either end in '1, '10' or '100'. This covers all possible values except 0000.

Comment: Are you sure that javascript or php accepts variable length lookbehind?